# How do you count all unique groups that can be made with items

Tags: combinatorics

assuming you have `aabcc` and you want to count all the unique groups that can be made with them so:

```
[empty,a,ab,ac,acc,abc,abcc,aa,aab,aac,aacc,aabc,aabcc,b,bc,bcc,c,cc] 
= 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $0$, $1$, or $2$ copies of `a`, which is $2+1=3$ choices; similarly $2$ for `b` and $3$ for `c`. Multiplying, there are
$$(2+1)\times(1+1)\times(2+1)=3\times2\times3=18$$
ways to independently choose the number of `a`s, `b`s, and `c`s.

Answer (score 1):

You start with $0,1$, or $2$ $a$'s, (so $3$ options there), followed by $0$ or $1$ $b$ (so $2$ options there), followed by $0,1$, or $2$ $c$'s ($3$ options)

Total: $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3=18$ options